# How to display image from database with Laravel and react hooks

Tags: laravel, react-hooks

I am new in reactjs I want to display image with Laravel and react hooks any easy way and fast to load image from Laravel path.?

Answer (score 0):

there’s a lot of way to handle display image :

1. store your file path to db, so you can call your image using path
2. store you image to db using blob type (but i don’t recommend this approach because it will make your db size increases significantly)
3. you can store your image to aws / another cloud services

From my experience, it’s better to store path only into the database then store image file in your system. because it have better performance than store the image to db. the disadvantage using this approach is while you have to backup the images and db. or if you move the image manually, the path in db will not match with the actual image’s path. it will throw an error.

you can try using aws since aws give a free tier s3 storage.
For further information about use s3 storage, you can read Laravel documentation about the Filesystem for the technical use.